# How can I work around not being able to export functions with lifetimes when using wasm-bindgen?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to write a simple game that runs in the browser, and I'm having a hard time modeling a game loop given the combination of restrictions imposed by the browser, rust, and wasm-bindgen.

A typical game loop in the browser follows this general pattern:

```
function mainLoop() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

If I were to model this exact pattern in rust/wasm-bindgen, it would look like this:

```
let main_loop = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
    update();
    draw();
    window.request_animation_frame(main_loop.as_ref().unchecked_ref()); // Not legal
}) as Box<FnMut()>);
```

Unlike javascript, I'm unable to reference `main_loop` from within itself, so this doesn't work.

An alternative approach that someone suggested is to follow the pattern illustrated in the [game of life example](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/implementing.html). At a high-level, it involves exporting a type that contains the game state and includes public `tick()` and `render()` functions that can be called from within a javascript game loop. This doesn't work for me because my gamestate requires lifetime parameters, since it effectively just wraps a [specs](https://github.com/slide-rs/specs) `World` and `Dispatcher` struct, the latter of which has lifetime parameters. Ultimately, this means that I can't export it using `#[wasm_bindgen]`.

I'm having a hard time finding ways to work around these restrictions, and am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to model this is likely to leave invocations of `requestAnimationFrame` to JS and instead just implement the update/draw logic in Rust.

In Rust, however, what you can also do is to exploit the fact that a closure which doesn't actually capture any variables is zero-size, meaning that `Closure<T>` of that closure won't allocate memory and you can safely forget it. For example something like this should work:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn main_loop() {
    update();
    draw();
    let window = ...;
    let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(|| main_loop()) as Box<Fn()>);
    window.request_animation_frame(closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref());
    closure.forget(); // not actually leaking memory
}
```

If your state has lifetimes inside of it, that is unfortunately incompatible with returning back to JS because when you return all the way back to the JS event loop then all WebAssembly stack frames have been popped, meaning that any lifetime is invalidated. This means that your game state persisted across iterations of the `main_loop` will need to be `'static`

Comment: This definitely got me closer, but I'm running into a different issue now. I created a `Game` struct that wraps any types that require `'static` lifetimes to be declared.  I changed the `main_loop` signature to `fn main_loop(mut game: Game)` and have the closure `move` game. 

This doesn't work because now the closure can't be wrapped by a wasm `Closure`. It would seem the only other option is to use `unsafe` and declare a `static mut` to hold the game state. Or is there another cleaner solution still?

Comment: Hm I'm not sure I quite follow what isn't working with the new `game: Game`, do you have a gist of the error message for why it can't be wrapped in a wasm `Closure`?

Comment: The issue is that by adding `move` the closure becomes a `FnOnce`, which is incompatible with `Closure::wrap()`. This makes sense given that there is no way to statically guarantee that a `FnOnce` wrapped by by `Closure` is actually only run once in js land. By the way, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh right yeah, I see! For that you can work around it for now by using an `Option<T>` followed by `take` to let it be a `FnMut` closure (but panic if invoked twice). This is something we should add support for in `wasm-bindgen` as well! (`FnOnce` closures)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Rust novice, but here's how I addressed the same issue.

You can eliminate the problematic `window.request_animation_frame` recursion and implement an FPS cap at the same time by invoking `window.request_animation_frame` from a `window.set_interval` callback which checks a `Rc<RefCell<bool>>` or something to see if there's an animation frame request still pending. I'm not sure if the inactive tab behavior will be any different in practice.

I put the bool into my application state since I'm using an `Rc<RefCell<...>>` to that anyway for other event handling. I haven't checked that this below compiles as is, but here's the relevant parts of how I'm doing this:

```
pub struct MyGame {
    ...
    should_request_render: bool, // Don't request another render until the previous runs, init to false since we'll fire the first one immediately.
}

...

let window = web_sys::window().expect("should have a window in this context");
let application_reference = Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyGame::new()));

let request_animation_frame = { // request_animation_frame is not forgotten! Its ownership is moved into the timer callback.
    let application_reference = application_reference.clone();
    let request_animation_frame_callback = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        let mut application = application_reference.borrow_mut();
        application.should_request_render = true;
        application.handle_animation_frame(); // handle_animation_frame being your main loop.
    }) as Box<FnMut()>);
    let window = window.clone();
    move || {
        window
            .request_animation_frame(
                request_animation_frame_callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
            )
            .unwrap();
    }
};
request_animation_frame(); // fire the first request immediately

let timer_closure = Closure::wrap(
    Box::new(move || { // move both request_animation_frame and application_reference here.
        let mut application = application_reference.borrow_mut();
        if application.should_request_render {
            application.should_request_render = false;
            request_animation_frame();
        }
    }) as Box<FnMut()>
);
window.set_interval_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(
    timer_closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
    25, // minimum ms per frame
)?;
timer_closure.forget(); // this leaks it, you could store it somewhere or whatever, depends if it's guaranteed to live as long as the page
```

You can store the result of `set_interval` and the `timer_closure` in `Option`s in your game state so that your game can clean itself up if needed for some reason (maybe? I haven't tried this, and it would seem to cause a free of `self`?). The circular reference won't erase itself unless broken (you're then storing `Rc`s to the application inside the application effectively). It should also enable you to change the max fps while running, by stopping the interval and creating another using the same closure.